# Git push: “fatal 'master' does not appear to be a git repository - fatal Could not read from remote repository.”

Tags: git, heroku

I accidentally deleted the folder ".git" and the login "heroku" in the folder with my project and want to update my files, but writes "fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository
Fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
And the repository exists. "
what to do? I do not have the right to change the application? How to access reverse? Command "git remote -V" does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the `.git` folder back. Try the following:

Recreate your `.git` folder

```
git init
```

`add` your remote

```
git remote add origin your_name@yoursite.com/something.git
```

Then `fetch` the remote branches

```
git fetch
```

Then `checkout` whatever branch you want

```
git checkout whatever_branch
```

Comment: still i can't push heroku master!